# How to use Custom Module Js to RequireJS

Tags: magento2, module, custom, requirejs

I add my custom Module to JS to **requirejs-config.js** File

```
    var config = {
        paths: {
            'Test/jquery':"Test_Header/js/jquery.min" ,
            'Test/popup':"Test_Header/js/jquery.magnific-popup" ,
            'Test/three':"Test_Header/js/three" ,
            'Test/async':"Test_Header/js/async" ,
            'Test/orbit':"Test_Header/js/OrbitControls" ,
            'Test/theta':"Test_Header/js/theta-viewer"  

        },
        shim: {
            'Test/jquery': {
                deps: ['jquery']
            },
            'Test/popup': {
                deps: ['jquery']
            },
            'Test/three': {
                deps: ['jquery']
            },
            'Test/async': {
                deps: ['jquery']
            },
            'Test/orbit': {
                deps: ['jquery']
            },
            'Test/theta': {
                deps: ['jquery']
            }
        }
    };
```

After I call this js to Template File:

```
    require(['jquery', 'Test/popup',  'Test/async', 'Test/theta' ],function($) {
            $(window).load(function () {
                $('#td').click(function () {
                    if(load==false) {

                        $('#threed').css('display', 'block');
                        $('.cpimage').css('display', 'none');

                         var viewer = new ThetaViewer( document.getElementById('threed') );
                         viewer.images = ["<?php echo $tsy; ?>"];
                         viewer.interval = 200;
                         viewer.autoRotate = true;
                         viewer.load();

                         }
                 });
            });
        });
```

Now All  Js File Are Loading Fine in **Net Tab**, But Throw Error IN Console **ReferenceError: async is not defined**

Reference:{async load }

[image: async load]

Reference: [async error]

[image]

All Js are Loaded, But throw this Error. I tested All js Are working IN locally fine, But, While Integrating Magento2(requirejs), throw this error.   Suggest Me  Why This Issue Occur and How to Solve this.

Answer (score 5):

`requirejs-config.js` mapping should be in below format. 
You need to load your **async.js** before **three.js** and **popup.js** because either **three.js** or **popup.js** depends on **async**

Try **below code:**

```
var config = {
        paths: {
            'Test/jquery':"Test_Header/js/jquery.min" ,
            'Test/async':"Test_Header/js/async" ,
            'Test/popup':"Test_Header/js/jquery.magnific-popup" ,
            'Test/three':"Test_Header/js/three" ,
            'Test/orbit':"Test_Header/js/OrbitControls" ,
            'Test/theta':"Test_Header/js/theta-viewer"  

        },
        shim: {
            'Test/jquery': {
                deps: ['jquery']
            },
            'Test/async': {
                deps: ['jquery']
            },
            'Test/popup': {
                deps: ['jquery']
            },
            'Test/three': {
                deps: ['jquery']
            },
            'Test/orbit': {
                deps: ['jquery']
            },
            'Test/theta': {
                deps: ['jquery']
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: I tried  you suggest , But still have  same  issue

Comment: @Rajkumar.E Try without shim. use this code - var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
           'Test/jquery':"Test_Header/js/jquery.min" ,
            'Test/async':"Test_Header/js/async" ,
            'Test/popup':"Test_Header/js/jquery.magnific-popup" ,
            'Test/three':"Test_Header/js/three" ,
            'Test/orbit':"Test_Header/js/OrbitControls" ,
            'Test/theta':"Test_Header/js/theta-viewer"  
        }
    }
};

Answer (score 0):

`requirejs-config.js` mapping should be in below formate.

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            noConflict: "Codilar_Place/js/noconflict",
            mabelJquery: "Codilar_Place/js/jquery",
            mabelSlider: "Codilar_Place/js/slider",
            mabelScript: "Codilar_Place/js/script",
            mabelScriptFile: "Codilar_Place/js/script-file",
            mabelSelectBox: "Codilar_Place/js/selectbox"
        }
    }
};
```

if you want to define dependency then define **shim** part.

hope this will help.